# Switching between textures in android with opengles

Tags: android, opengl-es

Can anyone point me in the way of a tutorial that will help me to understand how to switch between textures in opengles when clicking on a button?

Comment: Take a look at this, what you ask for is very specific, but this could be a start:
http://blog.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-vi-textures/

Answer (score 1):

```
in onDrawFrame

 use_program(program1)

   if(texture1 selected)
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texId01);
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);

   else if(texture2 selected) 
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texId02);
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);

   else
      wrong choice
```